# How to append extra field in json request of jmeter

Tags: jmeter

we have 10K payload requests in file, we need to hit each json file from jmeter but before passing the request few fields need to be appended.

For example
Before format

```
    {
  "data": [{
    "type": "articles",
    "id": "1",
    "attributes": {
      "title": "JSON:API paints my bikeshed!",
      "body": "The shortest article. Ever."
    },
    "relationships": {
      "author": {
        "data": {"id": "42", "type": "people"}
      }
    }
  }],
  "included": [
    {
      "type": "people",
      "id": "42",
      "attributes": {
        "name": "John"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

How to append below highlighted attribute

After format

```
{
  "data": [{
    "type": "articles",
    "id": "1",
    "attributes": {
      "title": "JSON:API paints my bikeshed!",
      "body": "The shortest article. Ever."
    },
    "relationships": {
      "author": {
        "data": {"id": "42", "type": "people"}
      }
    }
  }],
  "included": [
    {
      "type": "people",
      "id": "42",
      "attributes": {
        "name": "John",
        **"Gender": "Male"**
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of the HTTP Request sampler which payload you want to modify
2. Put the following code into the "Script" area:

   ```
   def payload = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue())
   payload.included[0].attributes.put('Gender','Male')
   sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).setValue(new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(payload).toPrettyString())
   ```
3. That's it, the PreProcessor will amend the request body in the runtime

More information:

- [Apache Groovy: Parsing and Producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)